# tmux not showing current working directory at beginning of line

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, tmux, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to use tmux only on my local machine but unfortunately the terminal doesn't print the current working directory.

A normal terminal prints `user@thinkpad:~` at the beginning of the line. But now it just prints the name of the folder I'm in. And there's also an empty space missing. So when I try to type something like `ls` it looks like this: `documentsls`.

I didn't change any settings when I installed tmux. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling it on my machine (Ubuntu 18).

Comment: Is this just a tmux thing .. Or does standard terminal do this as well?  Also does `pwd` work?

Comment: It's just a tmux thing. `pwd` does work.

Comment: in `/etc/tmux.conf` do you have the following lines? `setw -g window-status-current-format "#T(#I:#W#F)"` and  
`setw -g window-status-format "#T(#I:#W#F)" ` ??

Comment: This file doesn't exist on my machine.

Comment: What about `~/.tmux.conf`?